# How to install TokuDB on MAMP

Tags: mysql, php, tokudb

I'm by no means a DB admin. Just a hobbyist actually, and more of a programmer than a database person. I have MAMP 3.05, PHP 5.5.10, Mac OSX 10.9.3. I have a big suite of PHP applications and a gigantic database (several tables with over 1M records) using InnoDB. I hear that TokuDB is a big performance improvement over InnoDB, so I'm trying to install it, and having some trouble.

After some install steps, the doc tells me to start the new mysql instance using a command called `service`. This command is not present on my machine. Looking around, it seems that most linux installations have this command, but mine doesn't, and I can't figure out where to get it. Plus this idea of starting a new instance from the command-line is bothering me: I sort of thought that I could install this and continue to use MAMP as I always have, letting it start the mysql server, rather than me having to start it manually.

What is the correct way to install TokuDB to work with MAMP?

***Edit:*** In my terminal window, `uname -m` reports `x86_64`.

Answer (score 2):

According to the official [Tokutek documentation](http://docs.tokutek.com/tokudb/tokudb-index-quickstart.html#tokudb-system-requirements), TokuDB is only available for 64-bit Linux.

Comment: But my linux is 64-bit, as far as I know. `uname -m` responds with `x86_64`

Comment: Your question states that you are running Mac OSX, which certainly is not Linux.